# Use of 'self' from with a static function

Tags: ruby

I know of two ways ruby allows static functions to call each other within the same class...

```
class MyClass

  def self.foo
    self.say "self"
  end

  def self.bar
    MyClass.say "class name"
  end

  def self.say(text)
    puts "Using #{text}"
  end

end
```

Are there any subtle differences between the two syntaxes? Maybe performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, those are exactly the same. Performance-wise too. The only difference is code maintainability. If you decide to move a method with explicit class reference to another class, there's more work for you (or less, depending on a situation)

```
def self.bar
  MyClass.say "class name"
end
```

Oh, and there are no static methods in ruby.

Also, you don't need to explicitly use `self` to call a method there. `self` can be implicit.

```
class MyClass

  def self.foo
    say "self"
  end

  def self.say(text)
    puts "Using #{text}"
  end

end

MyClass.foo
# >> Using self
```

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: which one? I made a string of quick edits :)

Comment: `If you decide to move a method with explicit class reference to another class`

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: ah yes. :)

Comment: Thanks Sergio. The implied self looks better. But I guess it falls short for the same reason as `self`. That is, refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

No  there is no difference. Ruby is generous in offering multiple ways to do the same thing.